# Proving a function is L2

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lp-spaces

I have been trying to solve the following problem using Holder's or Young's Inequality, but I am just not doing the right manipulations I think.  It shouldn't require anything fancy.

Let $f \in \mathfrak{L}^2$$(0, 1)$, and let $g(x) = \int_{[0,x]} \frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$.  Prove $g \in \mathfrak{L}^2$$(0, 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f \in \mathfrak{L}^2$$(0, 1)$, and let $g(x) = \int_{[0,x]} \frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$.  Prove $g \in \mathfrak{L}^2$$(0, 1)$.

$$\int_0^1 g(x)^2 dx = \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^x \frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt \right)^2 dx$$

then, you use Jensen inequality (with a rescaling):

$$\leq \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x \left( x\frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} \right)^2 dt  dx$$

$$\leq \int_0^1 x\int_0^x \left(\frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} \right)^2 dt  dx$$

You intervert the integrals

$$\leq \int_0^1 \frac{f(t)^2}{1-t^2}  \int_t^1 x dx dt $$

$$\leq \int_0^1\frac{f(t)^2}{1-t^2} \frac{1-t^2}{2} dt $$

$$\leq \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1f(t)^2 dt $$